# Embed an AdMob ad in a scroll view with Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I'm attempting to programmatically place an AdMob banner ad within a scrollView. The current implementation that I have (based on the [Admob docs](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/banner)) places the ad at the bottom of the UI view and keeps it sticky when the user scrolls. This causes it to cover the content of the scrollView:

[image]

My initial thought was to create a UIView that would contain the ad placement and put that inline within the scrollview. However, when I use the function to place the ad on the new adViewContainer, it doesn't appear. I think it has something to do with which view it is being added to.

Here how I'm configuring the ad and calling the function to add it to the view. This is working fine:

```
import GoogleMobileAds

class VC: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {

  var scrollView: UIScrollView!
  var adViewBackground:UIView!
  var bannerView:GADBannerView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    //configure scroll view
    ...

    // configure ad view container and add to scrollview
    adViewContainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: yCoord, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 50))
    adViewBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(adViewContainer)

    //configure ad and call function to add to view
    bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716" 
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.delegate = self
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
    addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
  }
}
```

This function below is where I think the issue is. **When I change `view` to `adViewContainer` on the 3rd and 4th line the ad doesn't appear and I see an error in the console about constraints: Unable to install constraint on view.**

```
func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(bannerView) //breaks if view changed to adViewBackground 
    view.addConstraints( 
        [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                            attribute: .bottom,
                            relatedBy: .equal,
                            toItem: bottomLayoutGuide,
                            attribute: .top,
                            multiplier: 1,
                            constant: 0),
         NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                            attribute: .centerX,
                            relatedBy: .equal,
                            toItem: view,
                            attribute: .centerX,
                            multiplier: 1,
                            constant: 0)
        ])
}
```

I'm not sure the best way to resolve it, I'm a bit new to using constraints programmatically. Perhaps instead of placing the ad within a container view it would be better to use constraints to put it directly inline on the scrollView. I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

A couple changes to function that adds the banner to the view fix the issue and embedded it within the scrollview.

Specifically, I had to change the view that the subview is added to AND change the constraints `toItem` from `bottomLayoutGuide` to my ad container view.

Here is the updated function:

```
func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    adViewBackground.addSubview(bannerView) //Adds it to the ad container view
    view.addConstraints(
        [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                            attribute: .bottom,
                            relatedBy: .equal,
                            toItem: adViewBackground, //changed from bottomLayoutGuide
                            attribute: .bottom, //changed from top
                            multiplier: 1,
                            constant: 0),
         NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                            attribute: .centerX,
                            relatedBy: .equal,
                            toItem: view,
            attribute: .centerX,
            multiplier: 1,
            constant: 0)
        ])
}
```